# How to fix ssh connection that's been broken by dhcpcd service

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, dhcp

I'm accessing my Pi Zero W over ssh and I recently wanted to assign it an own network (I want it to host a webserver in it's own private network). I tried following [this](https://www.elektronik-kompendium.de/sites/raspberry-pi/2002171.htm) tutorial (unfortunately it's in german, but that doesn't matter since I'm stuck at the first command). I have added the following lines to my dhcpcd.conf:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.1.1/24
```

After restarting the service, my ssh connection immediately crashed and I can't get it back to work again. I tried accessing the file on my sd card and removing those two lines again, but for some reason the dhcpcd.conf file disappeared. Now that I have so limited access to the device I'm lost. What's the problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: *"I tried accessing the file on my sd card and removing those two lines again, but for some reason the dhcpcd.conf file disappeared"* -> As in, you looked in `/etc` and saw a bunch of stuff but not `dhcpcd.conf`?  Or you couldn't look in `/etc`?  I'm guessing the latter and that you can't access the root filesystem at all because you have assumed you can do it from a stock MS Windows box -- which is not true...

Comment: No, I'm on an Ubuntu system. It's the former, i can access /etc the file is simply not there.

Comment: Just checking.  There's nothing I'm aware of that will do that besides accident.  You might as well just replace it.  BTW, there should be lots of stuff around about how to do this that's not in German (unclear whether that's a problem for you); "own private network" == **hotspot**, except perhaps you don't have to forward traffic to the internet.  The usual center of that is `hostapd`.  *That's not the same thing as an **access point**, which is what jumps out from that page*.  An access point extends the range of an existing subnet, it never creates a new one, IP wise.

Comment: The PiZero has neither Ethernet nor WiFi, and would appear to be a poor choice. You will have to explain how you setup networking before anyone could even begin to guess how you broke it!

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add, that it's a Pi Zero W so it has an inbuilt network adapter. I set up networking via the wpa_supplicant.conf on Raspbian Buster Lite as it is described [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md) and then all I did was follow the first two steps on the tutorial page I posted.

Comment: Do you have a display/keyboard connected to the RasPi? If not, can you do it? And please don't expect that we follow linked tutorials, in your case already two, tl;dr. Please edit your question and explain what you have done.